# Trouble opening .fig files in axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, axes

I am creating a GUI in Matlab's Guide which should display a video and a plot saved in a .fig file. I am currently trying to open the plot in an axes element and while I know axes cannot be a container, the possibility of saving the plot in a another object and feeding that object to axes seems like a solution, but I don't know how to do that due to limited Matlab knowledge. Here is the only code I have for the button at the moment which allows me to open a file from my local directory.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  axes(handles.axes1);
  [file,path] = uigetfile('*.fig');
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you're trying to 'open' a GUI window created via GUIDE, by clicking a button, then you should know that this is not as simple as 'loading' the generated '.fig' file. See the comments in this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47437896/4183191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[file,path] = uigetfile('*.fig');` only gets the path and name of the file that was selected, it doesn't load the file.  To load the file you want to use,

`hfig = openfig(fullfile(path,file));`

However, since you don't really want to see the figure you  most likely want to use the optional input

`hfig = openfig(fullfile(path,file),'invisible');`

to load the figure but make it invisible.

Then you'll need to move the image from the axes in `hfig` to the axes in your UI.  This can be achieved in multiple ways, one of which is the use of [copyobj](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html).