# How can I plot a 3D data set with a 2D grid able to scroll through it?

Tags: plot, multidimensional-array, octave

I have the following (simplified) data file:

```
# Created on Fri Aug 27 16:48:30 2021
# name: M
# type: matrix
# rows: 5
# columns: 5

0 0 0 0 0 
0 5 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 

0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 
0 5 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 

0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 
0 5 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 

0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 
0 5 0 0 0
```

I need to use GNU Octave to plot these data as a 2D XY surface and be able to scroll across the Z axis.

This is what I did so far:

```
clf;
colormap ("default");

# Load data file in matrix M
load "./toy.data"

# Axes range
x = 0:columns(M);
y = 0:rows(M);

h = imagesc (x, y, M);
```

The result is what I expect; the only issue is that only the first XY slice is shown.

How can I make Octave read the next blocks, and shown them when I press two keys or when I move the mouse pointer to go back and forth with respect to my actual position?

---

With Tasos suggestion, I updated the file which now includes a slider and a (still empty) callback:

```
clf;
colormap ("default");

# Load data file in matrix M
load "./toy.data"

# Axes range
x = 0:columns(M);
y = 0:rows(M);

h = imagesc (x, y, M);

%% Add ui 'slider' element
hslider = uicontrol (                    ...
       'style', 'slider',                ...
       'Units', 'normalized',            ...
       'position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1], ...
       'min', 1,                         ...
       'max', 5,                         ...
       'value', 1,                       ...
       'callback', {@updateTime}         ...
     );

%% Callback function called by slider event to change time frame
function updateTime (h, event)
     %% TODO - Update CData
end
```

Comment: Do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43536882/4183191), but instead of plotting, use imagesc appropriately. Even better, use imagesc only once, and at each callback simply update the cdata of the existing image. This will be more efficient.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - From your example, I could add the slider to my plot, and the (dummy for now) callback function is correctly called. However, how should I update the CData value? How can I let Octave know it has to read the next matrix (next z value) in the data file?

Comment: If you capture your plot object at the time of plotting (e.g. `p = plot(...)` ), then you can set the `cdata` attribute (or any attribute in general) by doing `set( p, 'cdata', [ (...new data) ])`. To get a list of all possible attributes that can be accessed, do `get( p, '' )`.